# Detect if keyboard or mouse events are triggered by a software

Tags: windows, delphi, remote-desktop, keyevent, raw-input

Is there a way to determine whether the keyboard or mouse events are triggered from a hardware rather than an application like TeamViewer, Steam or some other remote desktop software in a desktop application running on Windows?

My purpose is not to prevent bots, but to prevent remote access to the application.

It seems that RawInput API lets me detect fake events sent using SendInput API. Is it correct?

Comment: Your lateral question (raw input) is not discussed in the post that your question is closed as a duplicate. If you want it to be answered (if it's not already elsewhere) try asking only about it.

Comment: The answers to the duplicate question don't cover another possible detection route - low-level keyboard/mouse hooks from `SetWindowsHookEx()` *do* report if input is real or simulated.  AFAIK, the Raw Input API does *not*.

Comment: @Remy - The older documentation for `GetRawInputDeviceInfo` had a note for 'hDevice': *"Handle to the raw input device. [...] It can also be NULL if an application inserts input data, for example, by using SendInput. "*. Can find it in for instance XE2's api docs. This note is removed from the documentation now, I don't know why, but `GetRawInputDeviceInfo` should normally be able to tell the difference.

Comment: I reopened the question. The comments and answers in the marked duplicate, all of them, somehow, seems to me that they've approached the problem in a quite roundabout way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The low-level keyboard/mouse hooks provided by [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) report if input was generated by actual devices or injected by application code.

For a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx), the hook provides a pointer to a [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) structure, which has a `flags` member that contains a `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag for fake input.

For a [low-level mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx), the hook provides a pointer to a [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx) structure, which has a `flags` member that contains either a `LLMHF_INJECTED` or `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flag for fake input.

Either hook can return a non-zero value to block the input from being passed to the rest of the hook chain, and consequently to the target window.

Regarding the Raw Input API, according to ([an older version of](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114060105/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597.aspx) <sup>1</sup>) the documentation for the [`GetRawInputDeviceInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597.aspx) function:

> hDevice [in, optional]
>   Type: HANDLE
>
> A handle to the raw input device. This comes from the lParam of the WM_INPUT message, from the hDevice member of RAWINPUTHEADER, or from GetRawInputDeviceList. **It can also be NULL if an application inserts input data, for example, by using SendInput.**

<sup>1</sup>: the highlighted note has been removed in the current version of the documentation, I do not know why.

So, the `hDevice` that is reported by a [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) message will be NULL for fake input.

however, it is not possible to block input with the Raw Input API.  You still need a low-level hook for that.

Comment: I tried using the SetWindowsHookEx()  but the  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT.flags value was always 128 (whether I ran it locally or through Remote Desktop).  Any idea why?

Comment: @SamGoldberg you would have to show your actual code (in a new post). 128 means bit 7 (the transition state) is 1, ie when a key is being released.